# Update ADO excel with two tables

Tags: excel

I'm trying to change values of an excel workbook using Update but something is wrong i.e. y want to get the value from table B and put it in table a

my code is this, can you help me?

```
UPDATE [Data$] 
 SET A.[D ArtN] = B.[D ArtC]
 FROM [Datos$] as A
 INNER JOIN [Productos$] as B
 ON A.[Art] = B.[ArtC]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE [Data$]
SET [Data$].[D ArtN] = [Productos$].[D ArtC]
WHERE [Data$].[Art] = [Productos$].[ArtC]
```

Is the correct format of an update statement. I'm not sure that this is the correct SQL syntax, as you did not specify if what you were using in Excel.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Sorry because of the ambiguous question, my two tables are in the same workbook and I want to change values in field table1.[D ArtN] when values in field table1.[Art] are equals to field table2.[ArtC], I wrote the refered code but excel returns me "Syntax error (missing operator) in expression..."